# How to add text to a page using python selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm trying to enter text into a text box using python selenium.

The html looks like below:

```
<div class="sendBox placeholder" contenteditable="true" data-placeholder="Type a message or drop attachment..." id="sendMessage" style="height: 375px;"></div>
```

After manually typing 'TEST' into the text box, the html looks like this:

```
<div class="sendBox placeholder" contenteditable="true" data-placeholder="Type a message or drop attachment..." id="sendMessage" style="height: 375px;">TEST</div>
```

I've tried the following code, but there is no response

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='sendMessage']").send_keys("testing")
```

However, if I manually click on the text box so that the cursor shows up and then enter in that code, it does work. I haven't been able to figure out how to make the curser show up via python selenium. I've tried the below though.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='sendMessage']").click()
```

Comment: What would happen if you first click the element and then send keys to it? Any errors? Thanks.

Comment: right, so if I do the following two lines successively, there is no error and nothing happens:  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='sendMessage']").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='sendMessage']").send_keys("testing")

Comment: Thanks. Could you also look through the markup and see if there is an `input` or `textarea` which is, probably, hidden, but has the same value/innerHTML as your content editable div?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like clicking and then sending keys to the element should help:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='sendMessage']")
element.click()
element.send_keys("testing")
```

You can also workaround it with setting the `innerHTML` via `execute_script()`:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].innerHTML = arguments[1];", element, "testing");
```

Comment: like I said, the first option you provided does not work. However, your second option is working kind of. For some reason, the text that shows up in the text box is 'arguments[1]'

Comment: @Chris oops, check it out now, please :)